# Why are my upvotes above 200 not counted if I later downvote a question?

Tags: discussion

Today I have earned 230 points from upvotes and accepted answers. But in the log I can see that I have earned another 40 or 50 points from upvotes which didn't count since the reputation cap was reached. Then I downvoted a question so that I have only earned 229 points today. So why isn't another 1 point from the upvotes added?

Comment: Downvotes are supposed to hurt.